# what is "Shock on shock heating"?

Tags: hypersonic

Can anybody enlighten me on the nature and physics behind what is referred to as Shock on Shock heating. Both , "Hypersonic: The Story of the North American X-15 , Jenkins and Landis" and "Lessons Learned from the X-43 Program published by AIAA", refer to this effect.

The static temperature jump though a shock is well described but this Shock on Shock heating seems to be an effect greater than the sum of it parts.
Both sources refer to flow within the Hypersonic regime.

thanks

Comment: [Is this what you are looking for?](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20160006018.pdf)

Comment: looks promising, I'll try and read it fully over the weekend, thanks

Comment: If you search for "Shock-on-shock heating" or "Shock-on-shock interactions" *in quotes*, you will find quite a few technical papers on the subject.